# How to use the in-built laser barecode scanner ( Android OS )

Tags: android, barcode

I did bought a terminal, well it's a phone kind of but seems to have more sensors than a usual phone.
Is there any way to be able to use those extra sensors, for example the laser barcode scanner.

Here's some details :
Company website
http://www.wizarpos.com/en/index.html
the terminal
http://www.wizarpos.com/en/images/homepage/homepage-product-img-4.png

Can't find any API to call the barcode scanner etc.., any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually these rugged smartphones, that includes a barcode scanner, make available some sort of SDK to integrate barcode scanning capability in third-party applications.
I've never heard before of WizardPOS (I work for Zebra Technologies and we've [multiple SDKs available for our devices](https://developer.zebra.com/community/android)).
Looking on WizardPOS' website I've not been able to find any SDK but you should contact the company that sold you the device to find out the correct API.